# Can the Firebase Auth API be used to identify the sign in methods that are enabled on the console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to be able to Identify the methods allowed for the app being used with Firebase 3.x

The console configuration for one of my apps below shows the following enabled:

- Email/Password
- Google
- Anonymous

I am looking for an API call using firebase to be able to check from the client what methods are enabled. Otherwise I will have to set it up I will only be showing those **sign in methods** in my client app dynamically for the enabled **sign in methods**, so I want to only turn on those views when the client is loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can check it with the providerId property of the current user

iOS: FIRUser
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/protocol_f_i_r_user_info-p#property-documentation

Android: FirebaseUser
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#exceptions

Web:User 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

Note: The email/password, anonymous and custom returns Firebase as providerId, you can differentiate anonymous of email/password and Firebase with the anonymous property of the User

Error maybe? in iOS specifically i've been receiving anonymous = true with custom and anonymous method, while in Android and Web seems to work fine

Comment: This is for each user. I am specifically looking to get the config methods enabled for the app.

Comment: Ohh ok you mean, to identify if your firebase DB has enabled a specific typeof auth from the client side?  Then there is no way and it could be a security flaw to enable any client to try to find what kind of security is enabled. Still  you can login with a dummy user and the authentication will throw an error showing if this method is enabled here are the specifics https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors#error_codes_common_to_all_api_methods

Comment: Not a security flaw. You will always have the auth methods exposed once you show your users the type of auth you are allowing. The auth method is secure at the core of the call not based on whether you know what auth you are allowing. Firebase does a good job of that already. I am just wondering if there is an API method that will let me know what auth methods (types) are allowed dynamically and create one component rather than having to wire them up in every app.

Comment: But maybe you only expose specific types of auth to specific types of users... that's why i said "could be" depends of what you want to share to each type of users, but i get your point the auth method is secure enough, still currently there is no method